# Flex - Function that compares strings in C

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I'm programing with flex using C, a C code compiler and I want to compare strings on a file, in this case my symbol table, with yytext. If yytext and the respective string of the table are the same one it should exit the function and if there are no instances on the table then the function will write the string down on the symbol table.

This is my function:

```
search (char *x){
int c;
int n = 0;
char *cdn;
while ((c = fgetc(comp)) != EOF){ 
   fscanf(comp, "%s", cdn);
   if (strcmp(cdn, yytext) == 0){
         n++; //if n>0 when it finishes searching the file then there's a copy on the file
   }else{}
   return 0;        
 }
  if (n==0){
     fprintf(comp, "%d\t %s\n", pos++, yytext); //will write if there's no copy in the table
  }else return 0;}
```

The input for the function is yytext, yytext will have for example "a".

After running this, the program doesn't write anything and it need to be closed manually. (More like program.extension has stopped working.)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The argument to fscanf is a pointer to a string buffer, which you need to ensure is long enough to hold the string. What you're giving it is an unitialized pointer, which will cause `fscanf` to attempt to overwrite some random address. It's highly likely that that will cause a segfault, but you might be unlucky. And the use of fgetc is unconvincing: are you trying to skip the newline character? Why don't you just check the return code of `scanf` (which you should do anyway).

Comment: Your symbol table should be in memory, not in a file.  Your function needs a declared return type (only archaic C doesn't require a return type on functions, and you shouldn't be learning techniques that were barely acceptable 25 years ago and have been unacceptable for all of this millennium). However, as your function only returns 0, it should probably return nothing so you don't have to check what was returned.   Writing `else {}` is pointless.  You do not know where the file `comp` is positioned when the function starts.  It isn't clear what `pos` is.

Comment: I'm using fgetc in the while to stay in the loop until it finds the end of file, I'm not so good with c, that explains the unitialized pointer being used I did check fscanf but not sure on what to do there. I'm trying to start reading the file from the beginning and copying every string to cdn to compare it with yytext. But I'm not sure about it all, can I initialize cdn to the beginning of the file and move it along the lines? (this is for rici). Pos is position for the symbol table.

Comment: Jonathan, pos is a global variable I've made outside the function and initialized it on 0, I'm using it for the symbol table. In the course I was given the option to write the symbol table on a text file and well I'm not even sure on how to make a symbol table. I was given around a week to make the C compiler and C is not one of my strong points. I was also thinking of writing the tokens for operators, reserved words and the string table on text files.

Comment: If you want to notify someone (e.g. me) that there's a comment for them, address the comment to them with the @ symbol (@Jonathan would work, for example).  Using a file to hold your symbol table is completely and utterly the wrong design.  It is so badly the wrong design that I'm not going to pretend to debug your code further.  There are many, many false assumptions in the code shown, too.  Please go back to the drawing board and use an in-memory symbol table.  That will involve dynamic memory allocation.  If you're not comfortable with that, you're not ready to create compilers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, putting your symbol table into a file is a very debatable design choice:

- symbols are checked very frequently, so file accesses will slow down your compiler a lot.
- symbols will be associated with a lot of grammatical informations (for instance, they may represent a variable with an associated type), so storing only the names will not be enough to make later stages of your compiler work.

If you store all symbol informations into a file, you will have to re-read the entire file and convert each bit of information into a memory representation each time you will want to access a given symbol.
This is not only inefficient, it will also force you to write tons of unnecessary and complicated code.

### Now for your `search` function.

Regardless of the current bugs, what your function does is *not* a search, though you need to search your file to make it work.

What your function does is create a unique list of `yytext` values. The "search" you're performing inside it simply makes sure an already present value is not duplicated.

The very first thing to do would be to give it a less misleading name, or modify it so that it does what its name implies.

### Now for the bugs

If for some reason you still want to use a file, I suppose you will put each name on a single line.
So why not use `fgets()`, that will take care of the line endings for you?

Whatever method you are using to read each name, you will have to provide a buffer with actual storage space for the string, not just an unitialized pointer.

If your input string is `yytext`, your `x` parameter will never be used.

Lastly, your `search` function (which inserts the current yytext value into an unsorted list), has no reason to return anything (except an error code if your disk gets full and you can't add new names to the list).